# How to open file in default app on iOS using FireMonkey

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey

I am writing an application in FireMonkey for Android and iOS. I would like to open a file from a URL in the default app on my phone (it could be a PDF, DOC, JPG, etc).

On Android, I do it like this:

```pascal
Intent := TJIntent.Create;
Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
Intent.setData(StrToJURI(URL));
SharedActivity.StartActivity(Intent);
```

How can I do something like this on iOS?

Comment: `StrToJURI(URL)` How does URL look like? This should not work on Android N/7+.

Comment: I do not understand that you need different code for iOs as i had understood you would write for Windows, Android and iOs the same time.

Comment: @blackapps Although Firemonkey is a cross-platform framework, it can't do everything in an abstract way. Opening a file in a default app is one of those things. Platform-specific APIs have to be used for that. That means using `ShellExecute()` on Windows, `Intent` on Android, `SharedApplication.OpenURL()` on iOS, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this code in my last project. Work fine on any platform.

```
unit u_urlOpenUnit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,
  System.Variants,
{$IF Defined(IOS)}
  macapi.helpers, iOSapi.Foundation, FMX.helpers.iOS;
{$ELSEIF Defined(ANDROID)}
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.Net,
  Androidapi.JNI.App,
  Androidapi.helpers;
{$ELSEIF Defined(MACOS)}
  Posix.Stdlib;
{$ELSEIF Defined(MSWINDOWS)}
  Winapi.ShellAPI, Winapi.Windows;
{$ENDIF}

type
  tUrlOpen = class
    class procedure Open(const URL: string; const DisplayError: Boolean = False);
  end;

implementation

class procedure tUrlOpen.Open(const URL: string; const DisplayError: Boolean = False);
{$IF Defined(ANDROID)}
var
  Intent: JIntent;
{$ENDIF}
begin
{$IF Defined(ANDROID)}
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW,
  TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(URL)));
  try
    TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(Intent);
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
//      if DisplayError then ShowMessage('Error: ' + e.Message);
//      exit(false);
    end;
  end;
{$ELSEIF Defined(MSWINDOWS)}
  ShellExecute(0, 'OPEN', PWideChar(URL), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
{$ELSEIF Defined(IOS)}
  if SharedApplication.canOpenURL(StrToNSUrl(URL)) then
    SharedApplication.OpenURL(StrToNSUrl(URL));
{$ELSEIF Defined(MACOS)}
  _system(PAnsiChar('open ' + AnsiString(URL)));
{$ENDIF}
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed!